# raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo

I am using Odoo 8 and encountered this error below:

`raise ValueError("Invalid field %r in leaf %r" % (left, str(leaf)))`

What does the error mean ?

Comment: It most likely means that you are using an invalid/non-existent field in the domain. Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: maybe there is some tag not closed well, please check your xml definition, and like @Naglis says 'Please post the full error traceback'.

Answer (score 0):

Leaf error arises mostly when the brackets are not closed properly or usage of un necessary brackets